# add two dictionaries that are already inside a dictionary in each row of datframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have dictionary that has two dictionaries inside it in each row of a column. Column name is 'price' and I have written two rows here:

```
row1 = {'offer_price': {'currency': 'GBP', 'value': 35.0}, 'regular_price': {'currency': 'GBP', 'value': 35.0}}

row2 = {'offer_price': {'currency': 'GBP', 'value': 55.0}, 'regular_price': {'currency': 'GBP', 'value': 55.0}}
```

I need to create a dataframe that has three columns, namely 'offer_price', 'regular_price' and 'currency', with the 'value' in both price columns and GBP in currency column.

I have tried but I am not getting the required dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()

for rows in df.price:

    x = pd.DataFrame(rows)

    df1 = df1.append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this command

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(row1)
```

It will permits you to create Dataframe from dict.

[Result for 'row1'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXnZw.png)

You can find documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html

I hope it will helps you !

Comment: no no, i have written that row1 and row2 are nothing but rows of a column that i have written like that.  it need to be iterated. i hv 300000 rows like that

Comment: And what is wrong ? You just need to iterate for each rows and concat your results to have a dataframe.

Comment: if i am using eval(row1) then its showing can only take str argument not integer

Comment: it looks easy but its not, also focus on the columns that i need.. please

Comment: Try to make a list of yours rows and iterate on it to use 'pd.DataFrame.from_dict(row1)'

Comment: i checked it buddy, class type of dcitionaries are showing string. now how to iterate over all rows so that i get dictionaries in all column inplace of string that look like dicitionaries?